# How to replace the same character with deferent value?

Tags: java, string, loops, replace

I'm facing a problem in replacing character in a string with its index.

e.g I wanna replace every '?' With its index String:

`"a?ghmars?bh?"` -> will be `"a1ghmars8bh11"`.

Any help is truly appreciated.
P.s I need to solve this assignment today so I can pass it to my instructor.
Thanks in adv.

So far I get to manage replacing the `?` With `0`; through this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name = "?tsds?dsds?";

    String myarray[] = name.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {

        name = name.replace("?", String.valueOf(i++));

    }
    System.out.println(name);
```

output:

```
0tsds0dsds0
```

it should be:

```
0tsds5dsds10
```

Comment: Please show your effort so far. Please post your code with a specific error/log.

Comment: You can't use replace as it will replace all "?" with the same string, 2nd argument.

Comment: any solution would be truly appreciated otherwise don't waste your and my time. thanks

Comment: Hint: Use a StringBuilder and iterate over the characters of your String. No need to split into an array. Append if not a ?, otherwise append the index value (as String).

Comment: post your full answer under an answer tab. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple replace operations, `String.replaceAll` is sufficient. For more complex operations, you have to retrace partly, what this method does.

The [documentation of `String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) says that it is equivalent to

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

whereas the linked [documentation of `replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) contains a reference to the method [`appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) which is provided by Java’s regex package `public`ly for exactly the purpose of supporting customized replace operations. [It’s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) also gives a code example of the ordinary `replaceAll` operation:

> ```
> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
> Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
> StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
> while (m.find()) {
>     m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
> }
> m.appendTail(sb);
> System.out.println(sb.toString());
> ```

Using this template, we can implement the desired operation as follows:

```
String name = "?tsds?dsds?";

Matcher m=Pattern.compile("?", Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(name);
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(m.start()));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
name=sb.toString();

System.out.println(name);
```

The differences are that we use a [`LITERAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL) pattern to inhibit the special meaning of `?` in regular expressions (that’s easier to read than using `"\\?"` as pattern). Further, we specify a `String` representation of the found match’s location as the replacement (which is what your question was all about). That’s it.

Answer (score 0):

In previous answer wrong read question, sorry. This code replace every "?" with its index

```
String string = "a?ghmars?bh?das?";
while ( string.contains( "?" ) )
{
    Integer index = string.indexOf( "?" );
    string = string.replaceFirst( "\\?", index.toString() );
    System.out.println( string );
}
```

So from "a?ghmars?bh?das?" we got "a1ghmars8bh11das16"

Comment: This is absolutely not a solution.

Comment: thank you very much, problem solved, note  that your print syntax should be out of the while loop :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work i have not checked it.

```
public class Stack{
public static void main(String[] args) {
String name = "?tsds?dsds?";
int newvalue=50;
int countspecialcharacter=0;
for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++)
{
    char a=name.charAt(i);
    switch(a)
    {
        case'?':
        countspecialcharacter++;
        if(countspecialcharacter>1)
        {
            newvalue=newvalue+50;
        System.out.print(newvalue);
        }
        else
        {
                System.out.print(i);
        }
        break;
        default:
                System.out.print(a);
        break;
    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

> Check below code

```
 String string = "a?ghmars?bh?das?";

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        Character r=string.charAt(i);

        if(r.toString().equals("?"))
           System.out.print(i);
        else
           System.out.print(r);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (more or less) replacing each target with the cardinal number of the occurrence (1 for 1st, 2 for 2nd, etc) but you want the *index*.

Use a StringBuilder - you only need a few lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
for (int i = name.length - 1; i <= 0; i--)
    if (name.charAt(i) == '?')
        sb.replace(i, i + 1, i + "");
```

Note counting down, not up, allowing for the replacement index to be multiple digits, which if you counted up would change the index of subsequent calls (eg everything would get shuffled to the right by one char when the index of "?" was 10 or more).